# Do these statements about pointers have the same effect?

Tags: c, pointers

Does this...

```
char* myString = "hello";
```

... have the same effect as this?

```
char actualString[] = "hello";
char* myString = actualString;
```

Comment: It looks like you have code that can be easily compiled and tested...why don't you test it?

Comment: He is not asking whether it works, or compiles. He is asking if both statements have the same effect (aka work in the same way). To which the answer is no.

Comment: somewhat related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2073079/what-does-compiler-do-with-ai-which-a-is-array-and-what-if-a-is-a-pointer

Comment: "Why don't you test it?" is a dangerous question when it comes to C and C++. Lots of behavior is undefined by the standard (and therefore it is generally wrong for programs to invoke the behavior), but this may not be apparent from simply testing the code.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

No.

```
char  str1[] = "Hello world!"; //char-array on the stack; string can be changed
char* str2   = "Hello world!"; //char-array in the data-segment; it's READ-ONLY
```

The first example creates an array of size `13*sizeof(char)` on the stack and copies the string `"Hello world!"` into it.
The second example creates a `char*` on the stack and points it to a location in the data-segment of the executable, which contains the string `"Hello world!"`.  This second string is **READ-ONLY**.

```
str1[1] = 'u'; //Valid
str2[1] = 'u'; //Invalid - MAY crash program!
```

Comment: I am assuming you meant `char str1[]` instead of `char[] str1`.

Comment: this is why some compilers warn you, unless you write `const char* blah="blahblah"`

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/349025/is-a-string-literal-in-c-created-in-static-memory/349030#349030) explains the reasoning behind this.

Comment: It's also why, in C++, initialising a `char*` to point to a string literal is deprecated in favour of requiring the pointer to be `char const*`. Not strictly relevant to this C question, I understand; however it does demonstrate the facts of the scenario.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that: in first example str1 pointer can't be changed. That is i cant do str1 = some_other_pointer. In second example, i can do str2 = some_other_pointer.

Comment: One little quibble - "creates an array on the stack and copies" ... only if the declaration is local to a function. In more general terms, the first one declares and initializes an array variable, the second declares and initializes a pointer. The first is equivalent (in any context) to char str1[13] = {'H','e', 'l' /.../ '!', 0};

Answer (score 4):

No. The first one gives you a pointer to `const` data, and if you change any character via that pointer, it's undefined behavior. The second one copies the characters into an array, which isn't `const`, so you can change any characters (either directly in array, or via pointer) at will with no ill effects.

Answer (score 3):

No. In the first one, you can't modify the string pointed by `myString`, in the second one you can. Read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/349025/is-a-string-literal-in-c-created-in-static-memory).

Answer (score 3):

It isn't the same, because the unnamed array pointed to by `myString` in the first example is read-only and has static storage duration, whereas the named array in the second example is writeable and has automatic storage duration.

On the other hand, this is *closer* to being equivalent:

```
static const char actualString[] = "hello";
char* myString = (char *)actualString;
```

It's still not quite the same though, because the unnamed arrays created by string literals are not guaranteed to be unique, whereas explicit arrays are.  So in the following example:

```
static const char string_a[] = "hello";
static const char string_b[] = "hello";
const char *ptr_a = string_a;
const char *ptr_b = string_b;
const char *ptr_c = "hello";
const char *ptr_d = "hello";
```

`ptr_a` and `ptr_b` are guaranteed to compare unequal, whereas `ptr_c` and `ptr_d` may be either equal or unequal - both are valid.