# char *p="orkut" vs const char *p="orkut"

Tags: c, pointers

```
 char *p="orkut" vs const char *p="orkut"
```

whats the difference btwn these two...

**EDIT**

from bjarne stroustrup,3rd edition page 90

```
void f()
{

char* p="plato";
p[4]='e' // error: assign to const;result is undefined

}
```

*this kind of error cannont be general b caught until run time and implementations differ in their enforcement of this rule*

Same with const char *p="plato"

Thats why iam asking the diffrence... Whats the significance of **const** here..

Comment: const makes for inviolate 'variables'

Comment: This might be helpful https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/STR05-C.+Use+pointers+to+const+when+referring+to+string+literals

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `const char*` variant is correct.

You should not change memory that comes from a string literal (referred to as static storage usually).  It is read only memory.

The difference is that the `char*` variant will allow you to write the syntax to change the data that it points to by dereferencing it.   What it actually does though is undefined.

```
//Option 1:
char *p = "orkut";
*p = 'x';//undefined behavior


//Option 2:
const char *q = "orkut";
*q = 'x';//compiling error
```

I would rather have option 2 happen to me.

Comment: Not all compilers require this, but the static data can very well end-up in read-only page/segment. So even when your compiler allows it, this can lead to wrong behavior (crash) at run-time.

Comment: but, the questions is, 'what is the difference between these two', not 'which is correct'? :)

Comment: Not strictly true. The `char *` variant will (more easily) allow undefined behaviour. Whether it will actually allow you to change the data is undefined. Whether the string literal is actually in read-only memory is also undefined. Both are "correct" in that they are permitted by the language and must be accepted by compilers.

Comment: @Charles: I clarified that I meant it allows you to write the syntax to do.... but clarified that may not match the actual behavior.

Comment: I think the answer seems more consistent now; it seemed a little contradictory before.

Answer (score 0):

A declaration of const char * p means that the thing p points at is const, ie should not change. I say should not because it is possible to cast away the constness. As has been pointed out, changing a string literal is undefined and often leads to an access violation/segmentation fault.

Not this declaration is different than char * const p which means that p itself it const rather than the thing p points at.

Answer (score 0):

The problem that Stroustrup discusses in what you're quoting is that in C++ a string literal will readily convert to "an rvlaue of type "pointer to char" (4.2/2 "Array-to-pointer conversion").  This is specifically so that the very common idiom of pointing a `char*` to a literal string wouldn't cause a bazillion programs to fail to compile. (especially when C++ was initially evolving from C).

If you can get away with declaring you pointer as `char const*` (or the equivalent `const char*`), you'll help yourself from running into problems like those described in the Stroustrup quote.  However, you might well run into irritating problems using the pointer with functions that aren't 100% const correct.

Answer (score 0):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2096448/do-these-statements-about-pointers-have-the-same-effect).

Basically,

```
char *p="orkut";
```

In this case, `p` is *supposed* to be read-only, but this is not enforced by all compilers (or the standard).

Answer (score 0):

note that more recent gcc implementations will not let you do

```
  char *foo = "foo";
```

they insist on the const (certainly in -wall -werror mode)

Comment: i should say thats for c++ not for c