# Strange Core Dump problem

Tags: c

My this code is dumping core :

```
int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
   char *p = "onnm";
   printf("%c\n",++*(p++));
   return 0;
}
```

What might be the reason in printf line ?

Comment: Your debugger should report what caused the core dump when you load it -- ie, is it an access violation, segmentation fault, misaligned read, etc.

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2096448).

Answer (score 3):

string literals are read-only, you can't change them.

Use e.g. `char p[] = "onnm";`

Answer (score 1):

You are able to code like this because of the "an inconsistency in the language standard" of C.
e.g.,

```
const char const_buff[] = { 'o','n', 'n', 'm', '\0' }; // OK

char* pArray = const_buff;            // not OK
```

In the same line it should have not allowed you to compile,

```
char *p = "onnm";
```

But you are able to compile, so allowing you to do the the mistake of changing a read-only string.

```
++ * ( p++)
```