# Why is literal string assignment in C not possible for array with specified length?

Tags: c, string, initialization, literals

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between char s[] and char *s in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704407/what-is-the-difference-between-char-s-and-char-s-in-c)
>   [Do these statements about pointers have the same effect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2096448/do-these-statements-about-pointers-have-the-same-effect)

All this time I thought that whenever I need to copy a string(either literal or in a variable) I need to use `strcpy()`. However I recently found out this:

```
char a[]="test";
```

and this

```
char *a="test";
```

From what I understand the second type is unsafe and will print garbage in some cases. Is that correct? What made me even more curious is why the following doesn't work:

```
char a[5];
a="test";
```

or this

```
char a[];
a="test";
```

but this works however

```
char *a;
a="test";
```

I would be greatful if someone could clear up things a bit.

Comment: They key is knowing the difference between assignment and initialization

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's examine case by case:

```
char a[]="test";
```

This tells the compiler to allocate 5 bytes on the stack, put `'t'` `'e'` `'s'` `'t'` and `'\0'` on it. Then the variable `a` points to where `'t'` was written and you have a pointer pointing to a valid location with 5 available spaces. (That is if you view `a` as a pointer. In truth, the compiler still treats `a` as a single custom type that consists of 5 `char`s. In an extreme case, you can imagine it something like `struct { char a, b, c, d, e; } a;`)

```
char *a="test";
```

"test" (which like I said is basically `'t'` `'e'` `'s'` `'t'` and `'\0'`) is stored somewhere in your program, say a "literal's area", and `a` is pointing to it. That area is not yours to modify but only to read. `a` by itself doesn't have any specific memory (I am not talking about the 4/8 bytes of pointer value).

```
char a[5];
a = "test";
```

You are telling the compiler to copy the contents of one string over to another one. This is not a simple operation. In the case of `char a[] = "test";` it was rather simple because it was just 5 `push`es on the stack. In this case however it is a loop that needs to copy 1 by 1.

Defining `char a[];`, well I don't think that's even possible, is it? You are asking for `a` to be an array of a size that would be determined when initialized. When there is no initialization, it's just doesn't make sense.

```
char *a;
a = "test";
```

You are defining `a` as a pointer to arrays of `char`. When you assign it to `"test"`, `a` just points to it, it doesn't have any specific memory for it though, exactly like the case of `char *a = "test";`

Like I said, assigning arrays (whether null-terminated arrays of char (string) or any other array) is a non-trivial task that the compiler doesn't do for you, that is why you have functions for it.

Comment: "Then the variable `a` points to where `'t'` was written" - no it doesn't. The variable `a` is an array, it has type `char[5]`, it doesn't point anywhere. The expression `a` decays to a pointer to the first element of that array variable in most contexts.

Comment: @SteveJessop, Ok I'm going to edit to be more precise.

Answer (score 14):

> char a[]="test";

This declares and initializes an array of size 5 with the contents of `"test"`.

> char *a="test";

This declares and initializes a pointer to the literal `"test"`. Attempting to modify a literal through `a` is undefined behavior (and probably results in the garbage you are seeing). It's not unsafe, it just can't be modified since literals are immutable.

> char a[5];
>   a="test";

This fails even when both `a` and `"test"` have the exact same type, just as any other attempt to copy arrays thorugh assignment.

> char a[];
>   a="test";

This declares an array of unknown size. The declaration should be completed before being used.

> char *a;
>   a="test";

This works just fine since `"test"` decays to a pointer to the literal's first element. Attempting to modify its contents is still undefined behavior.

Comment: Nice answer! In your last line, do you mean "... decays to a pointer from the literal" ?

Comment: @Nicolás: I meant the literal `"test"` has type `char[5]`, and arrays decays to a pointer to their first element.

Comment: Everything clear now! :)

Answer (score 3):

Do not confuse *assignment* and *initialisation* in C, they are different.

In C a string is not a data type, it is a *convention*, utilising an array and a nul terminator.  Like any array, when you assign it, it's name resolves as a mere pointer.  You can assign a pointer, but that is not the same as assigning a string.