# C/C++ int[] vs int* (pointers vs. array notation). What is the difference?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers, standards

I know that arrays in C are just pointers to sequentially stored data. But what differences imply the difference in notation [] and *. I mean in ALL possible usage context.
For example:

```
char c[] = "test";
```

if you provide this instruction in a function body it will allocate the string on a stack while

```
char* c = "test";
```

will point to a data (readonly) segment.

Can you list all the differences between these two notations in ALL usage contexts to form a clear general view.

Comment: Arrays in C aren't pointers, unless passed as a parameter. As for your example, think of `sizeof c` when c is an array and when it's a pointer. P.S. After reading your whole question, no, I don't think I'm ready to list all differences, those are basically different types and that's it. You may want to read the standards.

Comment: Even though the title is exactly the same, this question is actually a lot more informative. We should re-open it!

Comment: @ltjax And you're correct. My fault for getting trigger happy. Voted reopen.

Comment: ``char* c = "test";`` is a non-standard code. The correct one is ``const char* c = "test";``

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2096448/do-these-statements-about-pointers-have-the-same-effect)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

According to the C99 standard:

> An array type describes a contiguously allocated nonempty set of
> objects with a particular member object type, called the element
> type.

> 36. Array types are characterized by their element type and by
>     the number of elements in the array. An array type is said to be
>     derived from its element type, and if its element type is `T`, the array
>     type is sometimes called *array of `T`*. The construction of an array
>     type from an element type is called *array type derivation*.

> A pointer type may be derived from a function type, an object type, or
> an incomplete type, called the referenced type. A pointer type
> describes an object whose value provides a reference to an entity of
> the referenced type. A pointer type derived from the referenced type `T`
> is sometimes referred to as a *pointer to `T`*. The construction of a pointer
> type from a referenced type is called *pointer type derivation*.

According to the standard declarations

```
char s[] = "abc", t[3] = "abc";
char s[] = { 'a', 'b', 'c', '\0' }, t[] = { 'a', 'b', 'c' };
```

are identical. The contents of the arrays are modifiable. On the other hand, the declaration

```
const char *p = "abc";
```

defines p with the type as *pointer to constant `char`* and initializes it to point to an object with type *constant array of `char`* (**in C++**) with length 4 whose elements are initialized with a character string literal. If an attempt is made to use `p` to modify the contents of the array, the behavior is undefined.

According to *6.3.2.1 **Array subscripting*** dereferencing and array subscripting are identical:

> The definition of the subscript operator `[]` is that `E1[E2]` is
> identical to `(*((E1)+(E2)))`.

The differences of arrays and pointers are:

- pointer has no information of the memory size behind it (there is no portable way to get it)
- an array of incomplete type cannot be constructed
- a pointer type may be derived from an incomplete type
- a pointer can define a recursive structure (this one is the consequence of the previous two)

More helpful information on the subject can be found at http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/9/

Comment: "constant pointer to char" shouldn't that be "pointer to constant  char"? After all the pointer is modifiable.

Comment: "and initializes it to point to an object with type ‘‘constant array of char’’". In C++, but not in C. In C, the object `"abc"` has type `char[4]`. Nevertheless, attempting to modify it is UB. Might be good to point out the difference.

Answer (score 13):

```
char c[] = "test";
```

This will create an array containing the string test so you can modify/change any character, say

```
c[2] = 'p';
```

but,

```
char * c = "test"
```

It is a string literal -- it's a const char.
So doing any modification to this string literal gives us segfault. So

```
c[2] = 'p';
```

is illegal now and gives us segfault.

Comment: ``char * c = "test"`` is a bad C-code that yields warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]. Use ``const char*`` instead.

Answer (score 4):

`char []` denotes the type "array of unknown bound of char", while `char *` denotes the type "pointer to char".  As you've observed, when a definition of a variable of type "array of unknown bound of char" is initialised with a string literal, the type is converted to "array[N] of char" where N is the appropriate size.  The same applies in general to initialisation from array aggregate:

```
int arr[] = { 0, 1, 2 };
```

arr is converted to type "array[3] of int".

In a user-defined type definition (`struct`, `class` or `union`), array-of-unknown-bound types are prohibited in C++, although in some versions of C they are allowed as the *last* member of a struct, where they can be used to access allocated memory past the end of the struct; this usage is called "flexible arrays".

Recursive type construction is another difference; one can construct pointers to and arrays of `char *` (e.g. `char **`, `char (*)[10]`) but this is illegal for arrays of unknown bound; one cannot write `char []*` or `char [][10]` (although `char (*)[]` and `char [10][]` are fine).

Finally, cv-qualification operates differently; given `typedef char *ptr_to_char` and `typedef char array_of_unknown_bound_of_char[]`, cv-qualifiying the pointer version will behave as expected, while cv-qualifying the array version will migrate the cv-qualification to the element type: that is, `const array_of_unknown_bound_of_char` is equivalent to `const char []` and not the fictional `char (const) []`.  This means that in a function definition, where array-to-pointer decay operates on the arguments prior to constructing the prototype,

```
void foo (int const a[]) {
    a = 0;
}
```

is legal; there is no way to make the array-of-unknown-bound parameter non-modifiable.

Answer (score 1):

The whole lot becomes clear if you know that **declaring a pointer variable does not create the type of variable, it points at. It creates a pointer variable.**

So, in practice, if you need a string then you need to specify an array of characters and a pointer can be used later on.

Comment: const char *p = "abc";  creates an array

Answer (score 0):

Actually arrays are equivalent to *constant pointers*.

Also, char c[] allocates memory for the array, whose base address is c itself. No separate memory is allocated for storing that address.

Writing char *c allocates memory for the string whose base address is stored in c. Also, a separate memory location is used to store c.

Comment: We obviously both know what we're talking about, but it's reckless to say they are equivalent. Arrays decay into pointers, but that's not the same as *being* a pointer. In the same way `MyClass` is not equivalent to `int`, even if there is an implicit conversion.