# Questions about pointers and what is/is not a pointer

Tags: c++, pointers

Questions regarding, well, ultimately pointers to pointers (I suspect). Please read the questions posed in the commented code:

```
void doodah(char* a);

int main() {

    char d[] = "message"; // one way of assigning a string.
    // char* d = "message"; // another way of assigning a string, but REM'ed out for now.
    cout << d << endl; // d appears not to be a pointer because cout outputs "message", and not an address. Why is this?
    doodah(d); // a function call.
}

void doodah(char* a) {

    cout << a << endl; // this outputs "message" - but why?! What does 'a' mean in this context?
    // cout << *a << endl; // this outputs "m" - but why?! REM'ed out for now.
}
```

I am utterly confused! Please help.

Comment: `cout` prints the pointer to `char` as a C string, not its memory address.

Comment: `void main` is illegal C++.

Comment: Maybe it will help to try "std::cout << " d:\t" << d << "  " << static_cast<const void*>(d) << std::endl;".  Casting to "const void*" tells the compiler to ignore the type of d, and cout can then interpret and print it as a address.

Answer (score 2):

`cout` knows how to output strings when given a `char *`. It does not attempt to print the pointer value itself.

Comment: is an overloading used here ?

Comment: Yes, the `<<` operator has many overloads in C++. The one in use here is the one that takes an `ostream` and a `char *`.

Comment: and if i want to display the address of the variable ? should i use & ?

Comment: You would have to cast to something else, such as `cout << static_cast<void *>(a) << endl;` Using `&` would show the address of the pointer, which is different from the pointer value itself.

Answer (score 0):

An array is a bunch of objects next to each other somewhere in memory. The variable you've set the array to is actually secretly a pointer to the first item in that array (shhh!).

The biggest difference between `char *c` and `char c[]` is that the latter will be a `const` pointer, while the former is free to change. Also, C-Strings, like the one you have set there, are *null terminated*, meaning that the array ends in a binary 0 so things like `cout` will know when to stop iterating (this is also known as a *one pass last*).

For more information, you can read up on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11555997/c-c-int-vs-int-pointers-vs-array-notation-what-is-the-difference).

Answer (score 0):

This is what the pointer `a` looks like in memory:

> ```
> -------------------------------------------------------------
> |      | 'm' | 'e' | 's' | 's' | 'a' | 'g' | 'e' | '\0'     |
> |         ^                                                 |
> |         |                                                 |
> |        ---                                                |
> |        |a|                                                |
> |        ---                                                |
> -------------------------------------------------------------
> ```

`a` is a pointer to the first element of the string. When used in the stream inserter (`operator<<()`) the compiler will match it with the overload that takes a stream on its left hand side and a pointer to a character on its right hand side. It will then attempt to print every character until it reaches the null byte (`'\0'`) by evaluating characters at incremental addresses from `a`.

The stream prints addresses through the overload that takes a `void*` on its righthand side. You can cast your pointer to a `void*` or use the standard-provided `std::addressof()` function as well:

```
std::cout << std::addressof(a);
```