# Why the C string and Char Array and Char pointer differences in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, c-strings

Why does this:

**`const char cwords = "These are even more words";`**

result in an `**error**: cannot initialize a variable of type 'const char' with an lvalue of type 'const char [22]'`

but this:

**`const char * cwordsp = "These are more words";`** Work? (Not result in an error)

It seems like the pointer `cwordsp` should need to point to the memory address of that c string. Am I wrong?

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: No. That's exactly what it does. The first one is an error because a `char` is not a string.

Comment: I am sorry that is exactly what what does?

Comment: "the pointer cwordsp should need to point to the memory address of that c string"

Comment: So @AlanStokes why isn't a `&` operator needed?

Comment: I suggest you read section 6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/). It explains the often confusing relationship between arrays and pointers in C, and is also applicable to C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A C-string is nothing more than an array of characters.

So in addition to your working example, you could also do something like this:

```
const char cString[] = "Hello world";
```

Which is basically equivalent to this:

```
const char cString[] = { 'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd' };
```

Note that this is an array of `char`s, not a single `char`.

The reason that you run into problems with this:

```
const char cString = "Hello world";
```

is because `"Hello world";` can't possibly be interpreted as a `char`.  A `char` type expects just a single character.  Like this:

```
const char c = 'h';
```

Comment: So with the use of the pointer `const char * cwordsp = "These are more words";` `These are more words` returns a pointer to an array of `chars`?

Comment: Effectively, yes.  It returns the memory address of an array of characters.

Comment: No need for the address of / reference operator? And why doesn't the pointer need to point to a `char[]`?

Comment: No.  You're probably better off thinking of it as an array of characters.  That's really all it is.  Are you familiar with arrays (say, an array of `int`)?

Comment: yes, I am familiar with arrays, however it is this pointer to the array that is confusing.  If I have a single `char` I would declare it as `char * cp = & (aChar variable)`  So why with an array don't I need to specify that is is a pointer to a char array?

Comment: It's not a pointer to an array.  An array *is* a pointer to a contiguous block of memory which holds the values at the various indexes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81808/discussion-between-nhgrif-and-startec).

Answer (score 0):

In `const char cwords = "These are even more words";` you are initializing an 8-bit integer (`const char`) with a **pointer** to `const char`. This is an illegal conversion.

Comment: `char` need not be 8 bits. (And a string literal is an array.)

Comment: How is char not 8 bits?

Comment: It is required to be at least 8 bits. It is allowed to be more.

Answer (score 0):

Because char is 1 byte.

You are trying to put more than 1 byte in to a datatype which holds 1 byte.
const char cwords = "These are even more words";

In this example you create an array and get a pointer pointing to the first char in the array
const char * cwordsp = "These are more words";

A pointer array and a regular array is almost the same thing, but only almost. You can read more about that: [C/C++ int[] vs int* (pointers vs. array notation). What is the difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11555997/c-c-int-vs-int-pointers-vs-array-notation-what-is-the-difference)