# Array-style Linked list implementation C++

Tags: c++, dynamic, nodes

I am given a task to simulate a linked list structure, but using an array of Nodes rather than an actual linked list. When I call my append function, I want to check to see if my existing array is full, and if it is, I want to double the array size, and append my Node to the end of the "list" (array).

I am having trouble doubling my array size.

To give you context, here is my some of my .h file:

```
...
const int NULL_INDEX = -1;

struct Node {
    char info;
    int next;
};

class LList1 {

private:
    Node free [4];

    // When more memory is called for, the array will double in size
    // returns true if reallocation of memory was successful
    bool doubleSize();
    .
    .
    .
}
```

and here is the part of my .cpp file that tries to double the array size:

```
bool LList1::doubleSize() {
    Node* newArray = new Node[this->length()*2];
    memcpy(newArray, free, this->length()*2);
    free = newArray;
    return true;
}
```

I also tried using realloc and other functions. I keep having the same problem.
The line

```
"free = newArray"
```

keeps giving me this error in XCode: ***"Array type 'Node[4]' is not assignable"***

Please give me some insight into a better way to do this. All solutions online seem to work fine for arrays of ints, but not for my array of Nodes.

Much appreciated.

Comment: `Node free [4];` is a not a resizable array. Also `new Node[this->length()*2];` returns a pointer to the newly allocated array. `free` is not a pointer that can be re-assigned

Comment: That wouldn't work for an array of `int` either; you must be doing something differently for those. Your member needs to be a pointer.

Comment: What you are describing seems more like a dynamic sized array ([vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)), rather than a linked list.

Comment: @A.Sarid It's a linked list "inside" an array (`next` is the index of the next node).

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things are incorrect in your code:

1. Your `free` property is a static array. In your case you need a dynamic one, with proper constructor.
2. The `memcpy` command takes the size in bytes, hence you need to multiply by `sizeof(Node)`.
3. Perhaps it was intended, but the `doubleSize()` method was private.

Here is a corrected version of the code that compiles and runs:

```
...
const int NULL_INDEX = -1;

struct Node {
    char info;
    int next;
};

class LList1 {
public:
    LList1();
    ~LList1();
    int getLength();
    bool doubleSize();

private:
    int length;
    Node* free;

    // When more memory is called for, the array will double in size
    // returns true if reallocation of memory was successful
};

int LList1::getLength() {
    return this->length;
}

LList1::LList1() {
    this->free = new Node[4]; // Default size
    this->length = 4;
}

LList1::~LList1() {
    delete []this->free;
}

bool LList1::doubleSize() {
    Node* newArray = new Node[this->length*2];
    memcpy(newArray, free, this->length * sizeof(Node));
    free = newArray;
    this->length *= 2;
    return true;
}


int main(int, char **) {
    LList1 l;
    std::cout << "Original length: " << l.getLength() << std::endl;
    l.doubleSize();
    std::cout << "After doubling length: " << l.getLength() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting confused between [arrays and pointers](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_pointers_vs_arrays.htm). Your variable free is a constant pointer which cannot be reassigned. You need to change `Node free [4]` to `Node *free` if you want to modify its value.

[C/C++ int[] vs int* (pointers vs. array notation). What is the difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11555997/c-c-int-vs-int-pointers-vs-array-notation-what-is-the-difference)