# In C, does difference between char *s and char s[] apply to other types?

Tags: c, syntax

I have seen ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11555997/c-c-int-vs-int-pointers-vs-array-notation-what-is-the-difference), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10186765/char-array-vs-char-pointer-in-c))  that:

```
char s[] = "abc";
char t[3] = "abc";
```

are effectively identical to:

```
char s[] = { 'a', 'b', 'c', '\0' };
char t[] = { 'a', 'b', 'c' };
```

And the following:

```
char *word = "abc";
word[0] = 'd';
```

places `word` in read-only memory, causing the illegal memory operation `word[0] = 'd'` to error.

Is this only the case with `char`s? I can't get an error when I do something like this:

```
int array[] = {1, 2, 3};
int *p = array;
p[0] = 0; // No error here
array[1] = 1; // or here
```

Comment: Yes these behaviours are specific to character arrays and string literals. Read the C standard for full details.

Comment: Sincerely I don't know why they're down-voting your question.

Comment: In your first chunk of code, `t[3] = "abc" should be `char t[3] = "abc"; similarly in your second chunk.

Comment: The first two lines are **not** identical to each other. And there is no requirement in the standard for ROM. A PC with the OS running does not even have ROM. There also is no requirement to generate run-time errors. It is not clear what you intend or what you actualy problem is. The snippets are not even comparable and there is information missing.

Comment: Note that `word` is itself a modifiable variable; it could be assigned a new pointer value.  When you use `char *word = "abc";`, you are making it point to a character literal, which is treated as an array of characters.  Attempts to modify a string literal lead to undefined behaviour.  The string need not be in readonly memory (though these days it usually is).  An attempt to modify `"abc"` to `"dbc"` might succeed, and might also modify a string literal `"xyzabc"` to `"xyzdbc"` at the same time — or it might fail and cause the program to crash.  You should use `const char *word = "abc";`.

Comment: Hey Jonathan, you said that `char *word = "abc";` makes `word` "point to a character literal, which is treated as an array of characters." However, arrays of characters are easily modified. Using the above code, I could have said `s[0] = 'b'` with no problem. Could you please clarify?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It applies only to *string literals*.

A string literal implicitly creates an array object of type `char[N]` containing the character in the literal followed by a terminating `\0'` character. This object has static storage duration and is read-only. (It's not `const`, for historical reasons, but attempting to modify it has undefined behavior.)

When you write:

```
char *ptr = "abc";
```

you're creating `ptr` as a pointer object, and initializing it to point to the read-only static array containing `"abc"`. (You can prevent attempts to modify it by defining it as `const`.)

When you write:

```
char arr[] = "abc";
```

you're creating `arr` as an array object, of type `char[4]`, and *copying* the contents of the static read-only array into that object. `arr` is not read-only.

```
int array[] = {1, 2, 3};
```

creates an array object and initializes it as shown. There are no "integer array literals" that act like string literals. (There *almost* are -- see "compound literals" -- but those don't have the same read-only semantics as string literals.)

Note that this:

```
char t[3] = "abc";
```

is a special case: if an array is initialized with a string literal, and there isn't room for the terminating `'\0'`, then only the non-null characters are copied to the array.  As a result, `t` does not contain a string, just an unterminated sequence of characters.  This isn't particularly relevant to your question.

Comment: Thanks! This is a little off topic, but you wrote: "You can prevent attempts to modify [`char* ptr = "abc"`] by defining it as `const`." Any attempt to modify `char* ptr = "abc"` (without `const`) already fails, so could you please clarify what you meant by that? Edit: I'm probably overlooking the possibility of the program without the `const` prefix (?) on a computer different from mine.

Comment: If you write `char *s = "abc"; s[0] = 'A';` you'll *probably* get a run-time crash. (In fact the behavior is undefined; some implementations might not catch it.) If you instead write `const char *s = "abc"; s[0] = 'A';` then the error will be caught by the compiler. Catching errors early is (almost) always better.

Answer (score 1):

There's no exact analog for string literals for other array types. But you can come somewhat close by using a const-qualified compound literal

```
const int *p = (const int []) { 1, 2, 3 };
```

There is a chance it will be placed into read-only memory, and might crash the program if an attempt is made to modify it (after casting away constness that is). Another similarity with string literals is that const-qualified compound literals might share storage.

One obvious difference between compound literals and string literals is that string literals always have static storage duration, while block-level compound literals have automatic storage duration.