# Struct array assigned to pointer. What's happening?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

EDIT:
**What the difference between accessing an element in a array pointer via index `pointer[i]` vs. via pointer incrementation `pointer+1`.**
People are marking this question as duplicate to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11555997/c-c-int-vs-int-pointers-vs-array-notation-what-is-the-difference)
I have a hard time understanding how? Sure, it's a question regarding arrays and pointers, but the question similarities ends there. Sure, the references to C99 might help someone to dig deeper in C99.. but then, why use SO?
END EDIT

I have a struct (say defined so that all C files have access to it)

```
typedef struct
{
  uint8_t a;
  uint8_t b;
} task_t;
```

And in one C file (say Sub.c) I create an array of such structs

```
task_t ossList[10] = {};
```

which are further filled with values for `a` and `b` during runtime

In the same C file (Sub.c) I've written a function which enables other C files to get this struct array.

```
void HLP_GetStruct(task_t ** ossListGet) {
    *ossListGet = ossList;
}
```

The way I get the struct from other files (say Top.c) is by:

```
    task_t * ossList;
    HLP_GetStruct(&ossList);

    for (k=0; k<nTasks; k++) {
        printf("OssList  %d %d", ossList[k].a, ossList[k].b)
    }
```

And it's all good. But then when I looked more closely I wondered how this can even work. what's really going on?

In my outer C file (Top.c), I initialize **a** pointer to same type of struct.

```
task_t * ossList;
```

I then pass the reference to the other C file (Sub.c)

```
HLP_GetStruct(&ossList);
```

and in that C file (Sub.c) I point my pointer to the "real" ossList struct **array** and I somehow get a pointer **array** back!?

```
void HLP_GetStruct(task_t ** ossListGet) {
        *ossListGet = ossList;
    }
```

And I can access the indices by

```
for (k=0; k<nTasks; k++) {
            printf("OssList  %d %d", ossList[k].a, ossList[k].b)
        }
```

How?

(I've never done it like this before, my arrays have more or less always been declared as pointers, and pointer points by default to first element and you can "copy" over the pointer etc...)

Sub.c

```
task_t ossList[10] = {};
DoSomethingWithStructArray();
void HLP_GetStruct(task_t ** ossListGet) {
    *ossListGet = ossList;
}
```

Top.c

```
task_t * ossList;
HLP_GetStruct(&ossList);

for (k=0; k<nTasks; k++) {
  printf("OssList  %d %d", ossList[k].a, ossList[k].b)
}
```

Comment: Not really following your question. Your code is fine. Your global variable ossList[] is returned from the function.

Comment: Yes it's returned. But return to a pointer. I don't get the magic of when my initialized pointer in top.c becomes an array

Comment: Are you confused about how arrays are converted to pointer?

Comment: Exactly. As mentioned I'm used to pointers to arrays, where e.g pointer+k points to element k (or k+1..whatever) but confused about array converted to pointer array-ish... Which are accessed by element index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is that accessing `ossList` (as in `*ossListGet = ossList;`) gives you a pointer to only the first element of `ossList[10]`; your initialized pointer in Top.c doesn't "become an array", but ends up pointing to `ossList[0]`.

Since array indexing using `pointer[i]` is equivalent to incrementing a pointer by `i` (i.e. `pointer+i`), you can access the other elements of `ossList[10]` by simply incrementing the pointer to the first element (`ossList+k`) or, ideally, using `[]` (`ossList[k]`).

Comment: This was it. " `pointer[i]` is equivalent to incrementing a pointer by `i` (i.e. `pointer+i` )". Probably too simple LOL.

Comment: I hope you got your points before question got closed LMAO

Comment: Haha we're good, as long as you've understood the point here or in the duplicate link

Comment: The point here was crystal