# Confusing on pointer array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

The following is the C code:

```
char *ptr[100];
printf("%s\n",*ptr++);
```

My question is: we know that array name is not a variable (Ritchie's book "The C programming language" Page 99), so if we define

```
int *pa,a[5];
```

This is legal:

```
pa = a; pa++;
```

while this is illegal:

```
a++;
```

Here `char *ptr[100]` defines a char pointer array, so `ptr` represents the initial address of the array. For the above code, if `*ptr++` means `*(ptr++)`, this is illegal because array name cannot be used as a variable, and also it's meaningless because `*(ptr++)` still gets an address as opposed to `%s`. However, if `*ptr++` means `(*ptr)++`, it also looks strange... Can anyone help to understand this?

The above is my thinking process, my question is: how can `*ptr++` give us a string as the code `printf("%s\n",*ptr++);` says?

Comment: Your question is unclear. I don't feel I understand it.

Comment: What do you mean by saying *array name cannot be used as a variable*? `ptr` is a variable and it's also an array's name

Comment: I mean if `int *pa, a[5];` you cannot use expressions like `a=pa;` or `a++;`

Comment: See Ritchie's book 'C programming language' Page 99

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C/C++ int\[\] vs int\* (pointers vs. array notation). What is the difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11555997/c-c-int-vs-int-pointers-vs-array-notation-what-is-the-difference)

Comment: It's pretty much the same reason why `pa = ...` is allowed while `a = ` is not allowed: An array is never an assignable entity, but a pointer is.

Comment: Did you try to compile this code?  If so, did the compiler complain about it?  If so, what was the error message?

Comment: @John Bode I'm trying to understand the mechanism. It's easy to compile successfully because this example is from a textbook...

Comment: @Thomas - that's the point, `*ptr++` is a *constraint violation* (`ptr` is not a modifiable lvalue, and thus may not be the operand of the the `++` operator), and the compiler must *at least* issue a diagnostic for it (on the order of "invalid lvalue in increment").  Even *good* textbooks contain errors in code samples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postfix increment `++` has a higher precedence than dereference `*`.

Thus, `*ptr++` is interpreted as `*(ptr++)`. And as you've correctly figured out, `ptr++` isn't allowed if `ptr` is an array (of anything, values or pointers).

If `ptr` is a pointer, then `*ptr++` will indeed increment the pointer (so it will point to the next value *after* the operation), and this expression will return the *current* pointed-to value (before increment of the pointer). This expression is indeed sometimes used, e.g. for copying memory areas, e.g.:

```
while (...) {
    *dest++ = *src++; // Copy the current element, then increment both pointers
}
```

---

`*ptr++` *doesn't necessarily give you a string* — it gives you a string if and only if `ptr` is pointing to a string. And in this case, it's not necessary to post-increment just to get the string — `*ptr` would be enough. `++` is done for another purpose.

For example, it `ptr` is a pointer to an *"array" of strings* (i.e. a pointer to a pointer to a`char`, i.e. `char **ptr`), then you could print all the strings like this:

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    printf("%s\n",*ptr++); // '++' "jumps" to the next string
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. My understanding is `ptr` is a pointer-to-pointer which points to the address of `ptr[0]`, so `*ptr == ptr[0]`, `*ptr+1 == ptr[1]` etc. So if we want to get the string, it seems that we need to dereference again?

Comment: You are right about `*ptr == ptr[0]` and `*(ptr+1) == ptr[1]` (note the grouping). But in C, a "string" is _a null-terminated "array" of characters_. So if you dereference a string, you'll actually get the first character. 
Having `char** ptr` - this could be an array of strings; then `*ptr` or `ptr[0]` is the first string, `*(ptr+1)` or `ptr[1]` is the second string, and so on; `**ptr` or `ptr[0][0]` is the first character of the first string, `*(*(ptr + 1) + 2)` or `ptr[1][2]` is the third character of the second string, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this link should help you.

[C/C++ int[] vs int* (pointers vs. array notation). What is the difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11555997/c-c-int-vs-int-pointers-vs-array-notation-what-is-the-difference)

The array notation has a bounds limit while the pointer notation does not.

If you wanted to access the next in the array with array notation it would look something like a[n++] n being whatever the current index of the array you are at.  Where as assigning ptr to a sets ptr to the first index of the array and you can increment a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

`*ptr++` is parsed as `*(ptr++)` - apply the `++` operator to `ptr`, then dereference the result.

As written, this results in a *constraint violation* - `ptr` is an *array* of pointers to `char`, and an expression of array type is a *non-modifiable lvalue*, and as such may not be the target of an assignment or the operand of the `++` and `--` operators.

The line

```
printf("%s\n",*ptr++);
```

should (indeed, *must*) result in the compiler issuing a diagnostic on the order of "invalid lvalue in increment" or something along those lines.

Comment: Yes, you're right, there is `error: lvalue required as increment operand` when I use `*ptr++`. I listed all the possible solutions below. If you have time, could you please look at it for me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No. 1:

```
void main(void)
{
    int i;
    char *ptr[3]={"how","are","you"};
    for (i=0;i<3;i++)
        printf("%s\n",ptr[i]);
}
```

This prints out correct answer. Good!

No.2:

```
void main(void)
{
    int i;
    char *ptr[3];
    *ptr[0] = "how";
    *ptr[1] = "are";
    *ptr[2] = "you";
    for (i=0;i<3;i++)
        printf("%s\n",ptr[i]);
}
```

warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default].....Why can't initialize like this?

No.3:

```
void main(void)
{
    int i;
    char *ptr[3]={"how","are","you"};
    printf("%s\n",*ptr++);
}
```

error: lvalue required as increment operand....Why can't we use `*ptr++`?